# ORA12899 - creating a function which inserts boolean parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have the following function within a package:

```
FUNCTION FUN_GUARDAR_ENCUESTA(
    P_CENCUESTA IN VARCHAR2,
    P_XENCUESTA IN VARCHAR2, 
    P_IHOME     IN NUMBER, 
    P_BACTIVO   IN CHAR, 
    P_MENSAJE   OUT VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
  v_codigo_error VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO INC_ENCUESTAS(CENCUESTA, XENCUESTA, IHOME, BACTIVO) 
      VALUES(P_CENCUESTA, P_XENCUESTA, P_IHOME, P_BACTIVO);
    p_mensaje := 'Transacción Exitosa';
    v_codigo_error := '000';
    RETURN v_codigo_error;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_codigo_error := SQLCODE;
      p_mensaje := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
END FUN_GUARDAR_ENCUESTA;
```

but, whenever I test it it just the next error:

> ORA-12899: the value is too large for column
>   "INTRANETCORP"."INC_ENCUESTAS"."BACTIVO" (actual: 200, máximum: 1)

My table schema is this

```
COLUMN NAME   DATA_TYPE
CENCUESTA     NUMBER(8,0)
XENCUESTA     VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
IHOME         VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
BACTIVO       CHAR(1 BYTE)
```

I'm passing 0 as a value using a callableStatement with this query string

```
String query = "{ ? = call PKG_ENC_UTIL.FUN_GUARDAR_ENCUESTA()}";
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have boolean columns. What is the actual data type of the column (looks like `char(1)`, maybe, from the error), and what value are you passing in? How are you calling this?

Comment: Please show the table schema definition. I don't think there is a boolean data type for a table column?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, it's a char(1) column. I'm calling it using a CallableStatement passing 0 as my value.

Comment: @OldProgrammer done, i just updated the info with my table schema.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov yes, my mistake describing the problem. I also updated the function as you recommended. I'm trying to insert the value 0.

Comment: Well, not to argue, but the error message says you're trying to insert 200 characters into a field that's one byte long.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the right Java call; if you change it to the right one can you also show exactly how you're setting the parameters? I'm wondering if you just have them in the wrong order - there are issues setting named parameters in a different order to their position, so maybe it's something like that....